# Wordpress XML RPC API - Delete Posts

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to delete a post immediately, i.e. not move to trash, using the API? Also, is there a way to list the posts that are in the trash using the API?

Answer (score 0):

Which API you are using to interact with WordPress?

**Using simple PHP** you can use this function called wp_delete_post, with the flag $force_delete set to TRUE to skip the trash
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post

**Using WP-CLI** we can delete a post skipping the Trash. You just need to add this flag called: --force 
http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/delete/

**Disable Trash:** You can disable posts going to trash by adding this into wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0 ); // Zero days
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Empty_Trash

**Trashed Posts:** List Posts with Status Trash:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Trash

Comment: I'm using the XML RPC API (have changed the question title to reflect this)